# ¿Como extraer los números de los coeficientes de una ecuación de tipo string en C#?

Tags: c#

Exactamente quiero extraer los coeficientes de una ecuación.
ejemplo

```
x^4 - x^3 - 5x^2 - x - 6
```

los valores que quiero obtener son:

```
1
-1
-5
-1
-6
```

Asumiendo que esta ecuación sera insertada por el usuario la cual es una cadena de caracteres (`string`) variable, necesito que la solución al problema sea genérica.

No se si tenga algo que ver con restringir los números que a los que los anteponen el signo de potencia (`^`) ya que como menciono solo necesito los valores de los coeficientes y no los números de las potencias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar una expresión regular para capturar cada término:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches("x^4 - x^3 - 5x^2 - x - 6", @"(?:([+-])\s*)?((\d*)x(?:\^\d+)?|(\d))"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Group group in match.Groups)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}\t{1}", i++, group.Value));
    }
}
```

El programa anterior (puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[TIO](https://tio.run/##bU9dS8MwFH1ufsWlT8nalfn5YJEJor44ECf6sK4QulgDXTNyU4nM/vbuNhPxQUhOOId7zzmpcFoZq4ahQ93WsPxCp7Y5@8uyF@Vd9qzqrpH2zu@sQtSmRcgZqxqJCE/W1FZu2Z5F6KTTFXwavYGF1C1HZ8lqtQZpaxQsopnonRJl9QF8IR0924C6BcpQPguiQj4urGbrFG5iPr/iq2S6FgVOxJzzYjMRnsSiLDaJmH@TIEQsyD74R7dUzzQqe7PaqUfdKh4yslfZdErk44huHWi4hllgv40erOl2UAekRse1II7l/7Vehh9m98bSNI/3s75w@5M@TkEnSXr0@kkO0T2j0w/D4MtzmIIvzwgvfHk6ErqXBw)</kbd>) muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> x^4
> 0   x^4
> 1   
> 2   x^4
> 3   
> 4   
> - x^3
> 0   - x^3
> 1   -
> 2   x^3
> 3   
> 4   
> - 5x^2
> 0   - 5x^2
> 1   -
> 2   5x^2
> 3   5
> 4   
> - x
> 0   - x
> 1   -
> 2   x
> 3   
> 4   
> - 6
> 0   - 6
> 1   -
> 2   6
> 3   
> 4   6
> ```

Así que, en el grupo 1 de cada captura tienes el signo mientras que en el grupo 3 tienes los coeficientes de *x* y en el grupo 4 las constantes. Por lo tanto el siguiente código:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches("x^4 - x^3 - 5x^2 - x - 6", @"(?:([+-])\s*)?((\d*)x(?:\^\d+)?|(\d))"))
    {
        String signo = String.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[1].Value) ? "+" : match.Groups[1].Value;
        String coeficiente = String.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[3].Value) ?
            (String.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[4].Value) ? "1": match.Groups[4].Value) :
            match.Groups[3].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}\t->\tCoeficiente {1}{2}", match.Value, signo, coeficiente));
    }
}
```

Muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> x^4    -> Coeficiente +1
> - x^3  -> Coeficiente -1
> - 5x^2 -> Coeficiente -5
> - x    -> Coeficiente -1
> - 6    -> Coeficiente -6
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Pues una forma sencilla y fácil en cuanto a código sería separar cada ecuaciones en otras más pequeñas delimitadas por su operador, el problema es que si hacemos un string.Split(), perdemos el operador por lo que habrá que hacerlo manualmente:

```
string ecuacion = "x^4 - x^3 - 5x^2 - x - 6";

        ecuacion = ecuacion.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        char[] delimitadores = new char[] { '-', '+', '*', '/' };

        List<string> subEcuaciones = new List<string>();
        string subEcuacion = string.Empty;

        foreach (char caracter in ecuacion)
        {
            if (delimitadores.Contains(caracter))
            {
                subEcuaciones.Add(subEcuacion);
                subEcuacion = string.Empty;
            }
            subEcuacion += caracter;
        }

        subEcuaciones.Add(subEcuacion);
```

Una vez que tenemos cada sub ecuación, basará con comprobar el primer y segundo elemento de cada sub string para pintar el valor que le corresponda:

```
        foreach (string ecuaciones in subEcuaciones)
        {
            Console.Write(ecuaciones + ": ");

            if (ecuaciones[0] == '-' && char.IsDigit(ecuaciones[1]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ecuaciones[0].ToString() + ecuaciones[1].ToString());
            }
            else if (ecuaciones[0] == '+' && char.IsDigit(ecuaciones[1]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ecuaciones[0].ToString() + ecuaciones[1].ToString());
            }
            else if (ecuaciones[0] == '-' && !char.IsDigit(ecuaciones[1]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ecuaciones[0].ToString() + "1");
            }
            else if (ecuaciones[0] == '+' && !char.IsDigit(ecuaciones[1]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ecuaciones[0].ToString() + "1");
            }
            else if (char.IsDigit(ecuaciones[0]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("+" + ecuaciones[0].ToString());
            }
            else if (ecuaciones[0]=='x')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("+ 1");
            }
        }
```

Con mi cógido para : `string ecuacion = "x^4 - x^3 - 5x^2 - x - 6";`

Obtenemos:

```
 x^4: +1
-x^3: -1
-5x^2:-5
-x:   -1
-6: -6
```