# ¿Cómo conservar el delimitador cuando se usa string.Split()?

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

Supongamos que tenemos un string que representa una ecuación:

```
string ecuacion = "x^4-x^3-5x^2-x-6";
```

Y queremos obtener el espacio entre los operadores:

```
char[] operadores = new char[] { '-', '+', '*', '/' };
```

Si usamos `string.Split();` para separar los módulos entre sí en una lista de la siguiente forma :

```
List<string> subEcuaciones = new List<string>();
subEcuaciones = ecuacion.Split(operadores, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
```

El resultado que obtenemos es :

```
x^4
x^3
5x^2
x
6
```

Sin embargo me gustaría conservar el operador por el cual se delimitan, es decir, obtener como resultado:

```
 x^4
-x^3
-5x^2
-x
-6
```

¿Existe alguna configuración para conservar los operadores?

Comment: A voz de pronto lo único que se me ocurre es un método que vaya consumiendo caracteres y que cuando encuentre un +/- lo guarde y empiece de nuevo a consumir caracteres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Cómo conservar el delimitador cuando se usa `string.Split()`?

No se conserva. Y ese es el comportamiento esperado de `string.Split()`, según [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8):

> Split se utiliza para dividir una cadena delimitada en subcadenas. Puede usar una matriz de caracteres para especificar cero, uno o varios caracteres delimitadores (el `Split(Char[])` método), o puede usar una matriz de caracteres para especificar cero, una o varias cadenas de delimitación.

Es decir, usas *Split* para dividir una cadena, los delimitadores no los necesitas. De hecho en tu caso lo que llamas delimitador no es tal, los símbolos que mencionas tienen un significado semántico para cada una de las subexpresiones de tu cadena, **no tienen un significado delimitador**.

Echa un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/293568/2742) en que alguien se enfrenta al mismo ejercicio que expones.

Comment: De hecho yo mismo respondí a esa pregunta :P, fue por lo que me surgió esta pregunta al intentar hacer el split y conservar el operador

Comment: Ah, no me fijé @Fran. La pregunta no tiene sentido, lo que llamas delimitador no lo es… es como si preguntaras: "*¿Cómo me como el cuchillo después de partir el pastel?*" ¡el cuchillo se usa para cortar, no para comer!.

Comment: He modificado el cuerpo de la pregunta para que se adapte mejor al ejemplo :)

Answer (score 2):

Lo mejor es usar una expresión regular ya que `split`  no mantiene el delimitador.

En el siguiente ejemplo te muestro como se haría utilizando `Regex.Split`

```
        string ecuacion = "x^4-x^3-5x^2-x-6";
        char[] delimitadores = new char[] { '-', '+', '*', '/' };
        string delimitadoresunidos = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(string.Join("", delimitadores));

        string[] Separado = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(ecuacion, "([" + delimitadoresunidos + "])");

        for (int i = 0; i < Separado.Length ; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Separado[i]);
        }
```

**Resultado**

```
x^4
-
x^3
-
5x^2
-
x
-
6
```